# Remove invisible backspace characters from mysql data

Tags: mysql, hidden-characters

I have the following invisible character in my dataset

[image]

Which I believe is this character

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0008/index.htm

How do I remove this? I've tried

`` UPDATE events SET `value` = TRIM(REPLACE(`value`, CONVERT(char(8) USING hp8), '')) ``

Answer (score 2):

MySQL escape sequence for literal backspace character is **`\b`**.

See "Special Character Escape Sequences" here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

---

If I needed to remove that character from a string column, I'd use an expression like this:

```
 REPLACE(foo,'\b','')
```

I'd test that expression in a SELECT statement before I tried an UPDATE, e.g.

```
SELECT t.foo
     , REPLACE(t.foo,'\b','')` AS new_foo
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.foo LIKE '%\b%'
```

Comment: That seems to effect a lot of rows but doesn't get rid of it unfortunately :(