# How to use GROUP BY on varchar?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to group by two values because I want to remove duplicates from my database but somehow my `group by` clause doesn't want to work (the fields are in varchar). I also checked if there is a space or something more but there is none.

The server is a mariadb server, and I use a simple HeidiSQL Client

```sql
SELECT Player, COUNT(Player)
FROM Players
GROUP BY Player
```

I want it to simply group by so that I can remove duplicate values.

Here is the result I currently get :

[image: SQL query]

It's also the same with a SELECT CONCAT : 
[image: SQL query]

Comment: for ex: take a duplicate record `0rion59` then in a empty line insert quotes like ('') and paste that value and check whether there is space(white space or enter char). do it for both so result might be like '0rion59' and '0rion59
'

Comment: [**This answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql) fits exactly what you're looking for,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql)

Comment: Also please [**see this topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714534/mysql-database-with-unique-fields-ignored-ending-spaces) about whitespace in MySQL

Comment: @James Tried and they come out the same

Comment: @Martin https://i.imgur.com/K1QUV6c.png still the same and i'll look at your topic 2 sec

Comment: @Poli Then its better if you share the create table and sample data

Comment: @Martin If i do a concat it still give me the same thing https://i.imgur.com/iaWf9hE.png

Comment: It looks like those player names are using different characters. They *look* the same but are NOT identical.

Comment: i see how can i check it?

Comment: because i have a lot of them @Martin https://i.imgur.com/XD4e48B.png

Comment: Okay i think i founded was the character

Comment: It as an backspace is it possible in anyway to remove that?

Comment: Always TRIM just in case.

Comment: TRIM? @P.Salmon

And this don't work for me c: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420442/remove-invisible-backspace-characters-from-mysql-data

Comment: @P.Salmon i applied a UPDATE Players set Player = TRIM(Player); but it didn't seem to work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313803/mysql-remove-all-whitespaces-from-the-entire-column i tried this as well still nothing for me

Comment: It must be some issue in table definition/creation because the query is working fine. You can verify it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b8bca/1/0

Comment: Poli, please can you update (**edit**) your question with the [**Create Table Syntax**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739014/how-to-generate-a-create-table-script-for-an-existing-table-in-phpmyadmin). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I founded my answer, the problem was that there was a line break at the other lines so mysql couldn't find it with my `SELECT` i created a bash script to fix it :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
export MYSQL_PWD="YOURPWD"


runSQL() {
        runSQLOutput=$(mysql -sN --user="YOURUSER" -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 --database="Factorio-Stats")
}

runSQL <<EOF
        SELECT Player
        FROM Players
EOF

mapfile -t Players < <(printf "%s\n" "$runSQLOutput")
        for Players in "${Players[@]}"
                do
                        test=`echo $Players | sed 's~[^[:alnum:]/]\+~~g'`
                        runSQL <<EOF
                                SELECT Id_Players
                                FROM Players
                                WHERE Player = "$Players"
EOF

                        runSQL <<EOF
                                UPDATE Players
                                SET Player="$test"
                                WHERE Id_Players="$runSQLOutput"
EOF
                        echo "updated $test"
done
```

Comment: Good news! How did you find this out?

Comment: I did a huge select in heidi sql and i saw that one record open with a window and not the other... took me time haha thanks for the help!